# Defining a type for this function that works on arbitrary length tuples

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a parser combinator library and I need to implement a `map` function that takes `N` parsers in a tuple and a function that takes those `N` arguments and returns a parser that parses into an the return type of the function.

```
<A, B, Z>(ps: [a: Parser<A>, b: Parser<B>], f: (a: A, b: B) => Z): Parser<Z>
<A, B, C, Z>(ps: [a: Parser<A>, b: Parser<B>, c: Parser<C>], f: (a: A, b: B, c: C) => Z): Parser<Z>
// etc
```

I'm looking for a way to define the type of the `map` function for an arbitrary number of parsers.

I already have an implementation of this function except the types.

Minimal reproduction to play with:

```
type Parser<T> = () => T;

const string: Parser<string> = null as any;
const number: Parser<number> = null as any;

type MapN = {
    <A, B, Z>(ps: [a: Parser<A>, b: Parser<B>], f: (a: A, b: B) => Z): Parser<Z>,
    <A, B, C, Z>(ps: [a: Parser<A>, b: Parser<B>, c: Parser<C>], f: (a: A, b: B, c: C) => Z): Parser<Z>,
}

const mapN: MapN = null as any;

const p1 = mapN([string, number], (a, b) => [a, b] as const);
const p2 = mapN([string, number, number], (a, b, c) => [a, b, c] as const);
// const p3 = mapN([string, number, string, string], (a, b, c, d) => [a, b, c, d] as const);
// const p4 = mapN([string, number, string, number, number], (a, b, c, d, e) => [a, b, c, d, e] as const);
```

Is there a way to define this function for an arbitrary number of arguments while keeping the type safety?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=107#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJwM4QQHgCoD4oF4oAUAlHjhgNwBQlAxgPYB2SwUzCAlgwOYBcsiKdG05cc+BgFcANlKhwkchiCr0mLSQFsARqj7xkqNJp0IxUSTLkK4SqpVCQoAWThgAcnigBvSlD9Q0AEEAGigAIVCALSwCMCQ+AG04PQFDQKxQrRSDdDCsAF1QgDM+AmSoEKgs8JJcHEiibME0aODffyDQiKgAYSiYuMTy-Wb0zKbDPNCaCfQeguLS8srq7pne2vrG-hyWjMoAX2pVZigNVzc+F3dPC1l5RWVjxlOwAEZPc-cCBOFuUOMqEKhDgmU2UCSmXyVigJ2ARBULxYYAATJ8Lj8-lwARJtKgcXiEMCyplpuDIVVptCHnCEZQAPT02FIqBgADM6O+v2AHH+5lxJlCWKFPJExNBlNhoQAJuSJVppjLqQpaVRGcy1KyACyctyY0V8wEIEW87H8wkEkzi0lSqDS0IQOU2mgyh3KjXMBFAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with recursive tuple iteration.

This works by iterating through P (the tuple of parsers) and inferring the first element at a time (see `P extends readonly [Parser<infer R>, ...(infer Tail)]` line).

We then pass this back into the second result (`T`) parameter of `ExtractParserReturnTuple` until we hit the base case of only one element left in the input array (P) at `P extends readonly [Parser<infer R>]` at which point we merge `R` into the result tuple `T`.

This works for an arbitrary number of parameters. Unfortunately you need to add an as const declaration to both your input parsers and your inner function's return type. As I understand it this is a limitation with how readonly works - perhaps there's another way I'm not aware of.

```js
type Parser<T> = () => T;

const string: Parser<string> = null as any;
const number: Parser<number> = null as any;

type ExtractParserReturnTuple<P extends readonly Parser<any>[], T extends any[] = []> = 
    P extends readonly [Parser<infer R>]
        ? readonly [...T, R]
    : P extends readonly [Parser<infer R>, ...(infer Tail)]
        ? Tail extends readonly Parser<any>[]
            ? ExtractParserReturnTuple<Tail, [...T, R]>
            : readonly []
        : readonly [];


function mapN<P extends readonly Parser<any>[], R>(parsers: P, func: (...args: ExtractParserReturnTuple<P>) => R): R {
    return null as unknown as R;
}

const p1 = mapN([string, number] as const, (a, b) => [a, b] as const);
const p2 = mapN([string, number, number] as const, (a, b, c) => [a, b, c] as const);
const p3 = mapN([string, number, string, string] as const, (a, b, c, d) => [a, b, c, d] as const);
const p4 = mapN([string, number, string, number, number] as const, (a, b, c, d, e) => [a, b, c, d, e] as const);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=37&pln=20&pc=42#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJwM4QQHgCoD4oF4oAUAlHjhgNwBQlAxgPYB2SwUzCAlgwOYBcsiKdG05cc%20BgFcANlKhwkchiCr0mLSQFsARqj7xkqNJp0IxUSTLkK4SqpVCQoAUQAewBHBrB9ggEoRgCQQGDAkwKQg0GCgINwgGABMFBAg4BMYpEH4DdBsQLABtAF0AGigMGLjE5NT0hkzFEGK8KGKzSihO2ErgeKSoFLSMrIKfQ04AM1QoXywijq7FgH4B2uHWgDotjDLfecW9Hr6aofqRsfRJ6dmyrY2CK4RyuHYpIn3FrpWMF9lY3uqq1ODQuaDyhQ%20n0%20K1c7k83gEqH8gWCoXCkR%20rzKBTuOxmRSwCyhByBdQaxSJnz4gzJIyKdkoEwkDC87EYUA0cDAADkokdATT1qDwcVdlgCGBEcg9GUmSy%20AQ7oguEg%20LCPF4LsigiEwhEolgSLgcL4iHxfFAAN6UlIohjmaSyeRQZkAawYdAA7vbnb4qABfaiqZhQMAARhanJ5BAKwm4ZWMqCKVigweAZQIcDKWiNOAKWagWmTzrTRBUjBDYAATJGudyY3GuAmJNpUM3Wwhiwo0xmC1oyjRc60%20wOu6mK8Ay7QJ6GAMy16Ox9widsmMqN9fL7hjnuEEepsoJIf57MDw87idTtOhgAsC-rS448YdHc3T6bL7Xn6TKd3mdPB5QAkZQQMe%2040IeIEXmoU5AA)

Comment: I'll probably stick with generating code since type inference is really useful to have but good to know there's a possible solution (which will take me a while to understand how it works though)! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it's not the nicest thing to read, for sure writing overrides is more readable and maintainable. Hopefully there will be a nicer way to handle these kind of cases in the future. If you want explanation on anything in particular there let me know

Comment: So I went exploring with the idea of having to add `as const` in both places and came up with this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mu3mif?file=index.ts (TS Playground URL is too long to paste here). It seems to me the inferred type is identical to what your code does. What do you think? Did I miss something?

Comment: oh nice! yeah much cleaner, I didn't realise you could use mapped types like that with arrays, feel free to post as an answer and accept instead !